# How to add new column to dataframe from dataframe dictionary column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

I want to add columns to my dataframe based on the dictionary values which I have inside a dataframe column

| attendanceDetails |
| --- |
| "[{'clockIn': '1669435507', 'clockOut': '1669468193', 'actionBy': '', 'actionByName': '', 'actionById': '', 'actionRemark': '', 'actionByTimeStamp': None, 'deviceNameClockIn': '119', 'deviceNumberClockIn': '', 'deviceLocationIdClockIn': '', 'deviceLocationClockIn': '8th', 'deviceNameClockOut': '', 'deviceNumberClockOut': '', 'deviceLocationIdClockOut': '', 'deviceLocationClockOut': '8th'}]" |

I want to extract attendancedDetails data into a new column based on the key

Please help me with this

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import ast

df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['attendanceDetails'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0]))
print (df)
                                   attendanceDetails     clockIn    clockOut  \
0  [{'clockIn': '1669435507', 'clockOut': '166946...  1669435507  1669468193   

  actionBy actionByName actionById actionRemark actionByTimeStamp  \
0                                                            None   

  deviceNameClockIn deviceNumberClockIn deviceLocationIdClockIn  \
0               119                                               

  deviceLocationClockIn deviceNameClockOut deviceNumberClockOut  \
0                   8th                                           

  deviceLocationIdClockOut deviceLocationClockOut  
0                                             8th
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried doing this but it throws me an error "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x000002039A50FE80>
"

Comment: @Alonso - Can you try `df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['attendanceDetails'].str[0]))` ?

Comment: I tried with this but still it does not work

Comment: @Alonso - Unfortuantely this is real data problem :(